# How can I emulate the results of this if then then statement while using correct syntax?

Tags: syntax, syntax-error, ocaml

Working on an exercise for university class and cant seem to represent what I am trying to do with correct syntax in ocaml. I want the function sum_positive to sum all the positive integers in the list into a single int value and return that value.

```
let int x = 0 in    
let rec sum_positive (ls: int list) = function    
  |h::[] -> x (*sum of positive ints in list*)    
  |[] -> 0    
  |h::t -> if (h >= 0) then x + h then sum_positive t else sum_positive t (*trying to ensure that sum_positive t will still run after the addition of x + h*)
```

On compiling I am met with this error,

```
File "functions.ml", line 26, characters 34-38:    
Error: Syntax error
```

This points to the then then statement I have in there, I know it cannot work but I cant think of any other representations that would.

Comment: Are you looking for `x + h + sum_positive t`?

Answer (score 1):

You have `if ... then ... then` which is not syntactically valid.

It seems what you're asking is how to write what you have in mind in a way that *is* syntactically valid. But it's not clear what you have in mind.

You can evaluate two expressions in OCaml sequentially (one after the other) by separating them with `;`. Possibly that is what you have in mind.

However it seems to me your code has bigger problems than just syntax. It appears you're trying to use `x` as an accumulated sum for the calculation. You should be aware that OCaml variables like `x` are immutable. Once you say `let x = 0`, the value can't be changed later. `x` will always be 0. The expression `x + h` doesn't change the value of `x`. It just evaluates to a new value.

The usual way to make this work is to pass `x` as a function parameter.

Comment: Yes, pass `x` as an argument to a tail-recursive call, or not use any `x` but just plain recursion.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting an issue that had involved the parameter of , I believe it was because I was trying to add an int value to function of type int list. This is what I ended up with.

```
let rec sum_positive = function
|[] -> 0
|h::t -> if h > 0 then h + (sum_positive t) else sum_positive t
```

a lot simpler than I thought it out to be.

Comment: And you can simplify it even more by using one of the fold functions.